# Using http.get with a parameter

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a ui-grid with some rows.
I added a column with a link to access the details of the row and show it in a new (angularjs) view.
The new view gets its data from a http.get command.
Is there any way to transfer the "selected row" parameter to the new view so the http.get gets the right details?
At the moment I use MVC routing, so there is a Controller in between the two angular parts.

Ui-Grid:

```
 $scope.gridOptions2 = {

        enableFiltering: true,
        treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible: false,
        rowHeight: 100,
        columnDefs: [
            { name: 'Trigraph', field: 'ZeigeTrigraphen', width: '10%' },
            { name: 'Titel', field: 'Titel', cellTemplate: '<td style="word-wrap:break-word;padding:5px;">{{ COL_FIELD }}</td>' },
            {name: 'Aktionen',field:'AlarmkalenderId',cellTemplate:'<a href="/Details/{{COL_FIELD}}" id="Details" class="btn btn-success" )"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"</a>'}
        ],
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi2) {
            $scope.gridApi2 = gridApi2;
        }
    };
```

MVC controller:

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {Viewmodel = ViewModelService.getViewmodel(id);
            return View(Viewmodel)
        }
```

http.get in the new view (the returned one above):

```
 $http.get('/api/Alarmkalender/HoleAlarmmassnahme').then(function (resp) {

            $scope.gridOptionsEinzelmassnahmen.data = resp.data.IndexEinzelmassnahmen;
            $scope.data=resp.data;
            $log.info(resp);
        });
```

WebApiController Method:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> HoleAlarmmassnahme(int alarmmassnahmeId=1)
        {
detailsAlarmmassnahmeViewModel = //getting Viewmodel from a Controller/Service

            return Ok(detailsAlarmmassnahmeViewModel);
        }
```

Routes:

```
    public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "404-PageNotFound",
            // This will handle any non-existing urls
            url: "{*url}",
            // "Shared" is the name of your error controller, and "Error" is the action/page
            // that handles all your custom errors
            defaults: new { controller = "Shared", action = "Error" }
        );
    }
```

Comment: would the id of the selected row not suffice to make the get request?

Comment: its a different view then the ui-grid and I am using mvc routing, so there is a "normal" mvc controller method involved.

Comment: What I mean is that on row click on your ui-grid you could make a function call passing the item id to the function that makes the http request and then redirect to the new view with the data from the http response.

Comment: Could you explain that using code, please?

Comment: can you post your routes pls.

Comment: no angular routing involved, since it is a mvc enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass data in a GET request, however you can add a query string to your request:

```
$http({
  url: "/api/Alarmkalender/HoleAlarmmassnahme", 
  method: "GET",
  params: {gridRow: YOUR_GRID_ROW_HERE}
});
```

or by adding directly **your query in the  url string**.

```
$http.get("/api/Alarmkalender/HoleAlarmmassnahme?gridrow=YOUR_GRID_ROW_HERE")
```